# Is there a way of storing the original data lines in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using the `read_csv` method from pandas.

Say I am reading:

```
A,"B",C
```

With column names 1, 2, 3

I will get a dataframe of 3 columns, with the columns having values:

| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C |

I want to get a dataframe of 4 columns:

| orig | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A,"B",C | A | B | C |

For this scenario, re-creating the csv line from the 3 values is not possible as the parsing will already have discarded the quotes.

Is there a good way of doing this? I am currently directly manipulating the input to add the column to the incoming data, however I was hoping there was something within pandas itself that could help?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything dedicated to this use case, but I could be wrong. If speed isn't critical, I'd probably just load the data, then normally open the file again, put the lines into a series and add that to the df.

Answer (score 0):

The answer heavily depends on the data in a csv-file. If you are sure that there's no separator in quoted items, then we can avoid unquoting with `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` parameter:

```
# create dummy file
data = 'A,"B",C'
with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data)

# read the file with quotes untouched
from csv import QUOTE_NONE
pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None, quoting=QUOTE_NONE)
```

Ouput:

```
   0    1  2
0  A  "B"  C
```

In general, to see raw data we have to read them properly, i.e. without any csv-parser like `pandas.read_csv` or `csv.reader`